# Программно вызвать событие copy/paste/cut

Tags: javascript, html

На странице имеется *textarea*:

```
<textarea id = "txt"></textarea>
```

Задаю ему обработчики программно. Есть ли варианты вызвать эти обработчики тоже программно? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот синхронный метод копирования:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  var textArea = document.querySelector('#txt');
  textArea.focus();
  textArea.select();
  document.execCommand('copy')
}
```

```html
<textarea id = "txt">value 1</textarea>
<br>
<button>copy to clipboard</button>
<br>
paste here:<br>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Вот асинхронный способ копирования-вставки:

```js
document.querySelector('button#copy').onclick = function(){
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.querySelector('#txt').value)
}

document.querySelector('button#paste').onclick = function() {
  var textArea = document.querySelector('#res');
  navigator.clipboard.readText().then(t => textArea.value=t) ;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt">value 1</textarea>
<br>
<button id="copy">copy to clipboard</button>
<br>
paste here:<br>
<textarea id="res"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="paste">paste from clipboard</button>
```

Все перечисленное неплохо будет обернуть в `try-catch` или проверить наличие поддержки функций [иным способом](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Решил попробовать первый метод..однако, document.execCommand('paste') - возвращает false. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @Range с настройками безопасности например.. воспользуйтесь асинхронным апи

Comment: И снова спасибо.

Comment: @Range всегда пожалуйста